# C# - Returning mixed types in a function

Tags: c#, object, return

I have some different data types that i need to do something with in a function. Those data needs to be processed in the function and returned as an object i believe it is called.

This is some not tested code i just wrote here, but i think it displays what im trying to do .. I hope you guys can help me out how to do it.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     // Here im calling the function which returns data to the object
     object thoseProcessedData = SomeTestObject(5, "ABC", SomeOtherThing);

     // When returned i want to be able to use the different data like so. 
     string useItLikeThis = thoseProcessedData.newString;
     int numbersLikeThis = thoseProcessedData.newNumber;
}

public object SomeTestObject(int numbers, string letters, AnotherType anothertype)
{

     string newString = letters.Substring(0,5);
     int newNumber = numbers + 10;
     AnotherType newType = anothertype.Something();

     return processedData;
}
```

Please guys dont kill me, if this is a too stupid question. Im still very new to C# ..

If you dont get what im trying to do, please ask! Since my english is not the best i thought this way would be the best to show you what i want..

Comment: C# is statically typed. That means the type you declare things to be make a huge difference in what the compiler allows you to write or not. Here, `SomeTestObject` returns `object`. Why does it return `object` instead of some other type?

Comment: Not sure why the downvote. There is clear example code with the OP showing us what they want and the English is fine. There also appears to be 5 answers.. so this question isn't as unclear as one person seems to think. +1

Answer (score 3):

Well, you are on the right track (apart from the use of the `object` keyword/class)!
The `object` class is the base class of every reference type in C#, it has 3 or 4 functions, and no properties. You will very rarely *directly* use this class.

The *simplest* method to do what are you trying to accomplish what you want is to use a `Tuple`.

This would look like:

```
public Tuple<string, int, AnotherType> SomeTestObject(
    int numbers, string letters, AnotherType anothertype)
{
     string newString = letters.Substring(0,5);
     int newNumber = numbers + 10;
     AnotherType newType = anothertype.Something();

     return Tuple.Create(newString, newNumber, newType);
}
```

If, however, this is going to be used in other places, passed around, etc. you should create a separate object, populate it, and return it.

```
public MyDataClass SomeTestObject(
     int numbers, string letters, AnotherType anothertype)
{
     string newString = letters.Substring(0,5);
     int newNumber = numbers + 10;
     AnotherType newType = anothertype.Something();

     return new MyDataClass(newString, newNumber, newType);
}

//Somewhere else, probably another file
public class MyDataClass
{
    public string StringData {get; set;}
    public int NumberData {get; set;}
    public AnotherType ObjectData {get; set;}

    public MyDataClass(string myString, int, myNumber, AnotherType myObject)
    {
        StringData = myString;
        NumberData = myNumber;
        ObjectData = myObject;
    }
}
```

MSDN For:

[Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx)

[Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx)

Comment: Well, I think using in other places is not the only reason to switch from tuple to custom class - maintainability of code is on first place for me. Datatypes should be clear and self-descriptive. Otherwise you need to step into method to understand what is passed in Item2 (did that several times, don't like that very much) So, +1 for custom class :)

Answer (score 3):

Create class which holds data you want to pass and return:

```
public class Data
{
   public string Letters { get; set; }
   public int Number { get; set; }
   public AnotherType Thing { get; set; }
}
```

Pass it to method:

```
var data = new Data { Letters = "ABC", Number = 5, Thing = SomeOtherThing };
DoSomething(data);
// here data will have modified values
```

Thus class is a [reference type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx), all changes to its members inside DoSomething method, will be reflected in your `data` object reference. So, changes can look like:

```
public void DoSomething(Data data)
{
     data.Letters = data.Letters.Substring(0,5);
     data.Number += 10;
     data.Thing.Something();
}
```

Comment: +1 One of the most important things, especially for a beginner is to get in the mindset that code should be readable. Encapsulating data into a type, given an appropriate name goes a long way to make code self documenting.

Comment: @Jay thanks! Frankly speaking it's not best names, but I did best from information given :) Anyway data type with descriptive name, and descriptive members names is much better, than tuples with their Item1, Item2 etc :)

Comment: Coming up with names was definitely hard :) I would only suggest the Tuple if you seriously aren't going to use it except as a return value. I only included it in my answer as the "fastest" method, and even then you should know what you are doing (which, admittedly, a new programmer rarely does). For what Tuple was intended to do (replace small, throw away type classes) it does a pretty good job (while reducing readability of course).

Answer (score 2):

Create a class to represent that data:

```
public class ProcessedData
{
     public string NewString {get; set;}
     public int NewNumber {get; set;}
     public AnotherType NewType {get; set;}
}
```

then populate an instance of that class and return it:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     // Here im calling the function which returns data to the object
     ProcessedData thoseProcessedData = SomeTestObject(5, "ABC", SomeOtherThing);

     // now you can access those properties 
     string useItLikeThis = thoseProcessedData.NewString;
     int numbersLikeThis = thoseProcessedData.NewNumber;
}

public ProcessedData SomeTestObject(int numbers, string letters, AnotherType anothertype)
{
     ProcessedData processedData = new ProcessedData();

     processedData.newString = letters.Substring(0,5);
     processedData.newNumber = numbers + 10;
     processedData.newType = anothertype.Something();

     return processedData;
}
```

There are mechanisms (anonymous types, `dynamic`) that would make it *possible* to dynamically "find" properties at run-time, but defining a class and statically typing the return type is *by far* safer.

Comment: I would probably go with Value Object (i.e. keep property setters private) - then returning new instance of ProcessedData will be more reasonable)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your English is fine. Don't worry about that :)

Secondly, what you want to do is just create a class that has those properties on it.

```
class YourClass {
    public string NewString { get; set; }
    public int NewNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Then return an instance of this out of your method:

```
 return new YourClass() {
     NewString = letters.Substring(0, 5),
     NewNumber = numbers + 10
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you can create a simple class.

```
public class Data
{
    public string NewString { get; set; }
    public int NewNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can return it from a method.

```
Data ReadData() 
{
    return new Data { 
        NewString = CalculateNewString(), 
        NewNumber = CalclulateNewNumber() 
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you need to return more than one value, you need to create your own class. A class (among other things) encapsulates or "packages together" one or more pieces of data. Here is an example:

```
public class MyCustomClass {
    public int MyCustomInt { get; set; }
    public string MyCustomString { get; set; }
    public bool MyCustomYesNo { get; set; }
}
```

This class contains three properties. Properties contain data that can be read from (get) or written to (set). You can now write a function that returns an instance of this property:

```
public MyCustomClass MyFunction()
{
    return new MyCustomClass() {
        MyCustomInt = 15, MyCustomString = "Hello World!",
        MyCustomYesNo = true
    };
}
```

This function will create a new instance of our `MyCustomClass` and fill each property with values. And now you can call it like this:

```
MyCustomClass myVar = MyFunction();
int myInt = myVar.MyCustomInt; // Contains 15
string myString = myVar.MyCustomString; // Contains "Hello World!"
bool myYesNo = myVar.MyCustomYesNo;  // Contains true
```

Now of course, your function can do anything it wishes. I was just providing an example. 
Hope this makes sense!